# I need Visual Code Studio to Auto Suggest parameter details for my functions, Where and how I do that?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, annotations, type-hinting, signature

I need Visual Studio Code to **Auto Suggest parameter details for my functions**.  It does that for many in-build and imported.  It does auto suggest like:

```
(pattern: AnyStr@compile, flags: _FlagsType = 0) -> 
Pattern[AnyStr@compile]
```

How and where do I specify parameter documentation for my functions too, so that Visual Studio Code auto-suggest those for my function too?

Below is the image of auto suggest from Visual Code for an imported function.  I want to provide the same for my functions too.   **Where and how do I specify that for my functions?**
[Visual Code Auto Suugest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWvOV.png)

Comment: My question got marked duplicate and closed, is not correct.  The other question don't solve my problem.

I found the resolution myself.   The resolution is function annotation in python: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function-annotation 

If I annotate function "def f (a,b) :"  like "def f(a: int, b: list) -> None :", Visual Studio provide that as typing hint. 

One can enhance annotations further by importing python module "typing" using say "Union" etc. from the "typing" module